# vue-cli-service build heavier than vue ui build

Tags: vue.js, build, vue-cli

I build my VueJS app with `vue-cli-service build --mode production`, and my chunk-vendors.js weighs 3.2M.
So I decided to investigate why it's so heavy, using `vue ui`.
Then, I simply click on Build, and I see that `chunk-vendors.js` is now 1.0M !

Why is there a such difference between these two build?

Here the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

`vue ui`'s `build` command is this:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode production --target app --no-module --dashboard
```

Notice the `--no-module` flag, which turns off [modern browser builds](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html?#modern-mode), which is [enabled by default as of Vue CLI 5.0.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/commit/cd783766755fcb6b7e8c558984c58e2b8b305c09). Therefore, the command you're using (i.e., without `--no-module`) creates a modern build, which includes transpiled code and polyfilled bundles for legacy browsers in addition to slimmer code for modern browsers that don't require the polyfills. On the other hand, `vue ui` only builds the latter.